# Query across layers of SHP files?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, query, spatial-query

I would like to query features from a SHP vector that intersect with features from another vector.

Pseudocode:

```
 "Name"   IS  intersects( countries)
```

How would be the valid query composed?

Comment: Are you trying to select instances of 'name' that also exist in another shapefile? if so it would be quickest to join the data by attributes (Name) and then select where 'name' = related.name... be careful though, only *exact* matches will join; often I add a join_name field to both tables and field calculate upper case and trimmed join fields when joining strings - some databases are case sensitive but best not to take the chance and a leading/trailing space can ruin a join.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS requires you to use vector analysis operations in order to do spatial queries. You can't do it dynamically, like you can in MapInfo, for example.

Check out the vector menu, go to 'Vector' > 'Geoprocessing' > 'Intersects'. This will combine two files and write the result out to another file.

Comment: "You can't do it dynamically, like you can in MapInfo," Not yet but there is working code for it.

Comment: Yes, I know about spatial join. but it's a detour to always create a new file just to find those cites that are within a certain country (e.g. using NaturalEarth). 

@NathanW : this sounds great.

Comment: You'll need to use a spatial database, @dacoex, and then you can do it in real time with a view! PostGIS is surprisingly easy to get set up and use in QGIS.